# Удалить файл из wwwroot в Razor Pages ASP.NET

Tags: файлы, razor

Как удалить правильно файлы из статической директории wwwroot в ASP.NET Razor Pages.

Имеется метод:

```
private IActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            string fileName = "";
            MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(DataBase.GetConfig());
            try
            {
                connect.Open();
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from exampletable where id = '" + id + "'", connect);
                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                reader.Read();
                fileName = reader.GetString("file_name");

            }
            finally
            {
                connect.Close();
            }
            var fullPath = "/uploads/" + fileName; //попробывал wwwroot/uploads и ~/uploads
            try
            {
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(fullPath))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(fullPath);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex+"");
                Debug.WriteLine(ex+"");
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Читаю название с базы, файлы правильно читает, всё проверил дебагом, но удалить пропускает сам метод. Exception ничего не показывает в выводе.

как решить?

Comment: а вы уверены что файл существует по указанному пути, поставьте точку останова на Exists и проверьте

Comment: т.к. `/uploads` указывает на путь "с начала диска", `~/uploads` путь в папке пользователя, они и не будут работать

Comment: @ExplodingKitten, Вот как указать правильный путь? Как решить проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил: Проблема была в правильности пути.

```
        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
        private readonly IHostEnvironment _environment;
public DeleteModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger, IHostEnvironment environment)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _environment = environment;
        }

private IActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            string fileName = "";
            MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(DataBase.GetConfig());
            try
            {
                connect.Open();
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from exampletable where id = '" + id + "'", connect);
                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                reader.Read();
                fileName = reader.GetString("file_name");

            }
            finally
            {
                connect.Close();
            }

            var fullPath = _environment.ContentRootPath+"/uploads/" + fileName;

            try
            {
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(fullPath))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(fullPath);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex+"");
                Debug.WriteLine(ex+"");
            }
            return null;
        }
```